# Mongoose removing a collections with hooks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a project using MEAN stack, but I have a problem with Mongoose hooks.

I have these models:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    email: String
});

const ArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "comments"
  }]
});

const CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
  });
```

I have successfully created hooks for removing articles and comments on removing user:

```
UserSchema.post("remove", function(doc) {
  console.log("user remove");
  this.model("article")
  .remove({ author: doc._id })
  .then(data => {
    console.log("articles remove");
  })
  .catch(data => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  this.model("comments")
  .remove({ author: doc._id })
  .then(err => {
    console.log("comments remove");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

And hooks to removing comments references in articles:

```
CommentSchema.post("remove", function(doc) {
  console.log("comment remove");
  this.model("article")
  .update(
    { comments: doc._id },
    { $pull: { comments: doc._id } },
    { multi: true }
  )
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

I know that model.remove don't trigger hooks, but my problem lies in how can I trigger the hook in articles and what I have to do to remove existing comments when deleting user or that article.

I would like to take any advice that may help me with my project.